# Link not opening in same page

Tags: html, css, tabs

Little back story:

Our department has a 'dashboard' that we utilize for quick links and tools that we utilize often.  The guy that developed the original page found a new job - and no one else in our department knows HTML at all. I volunteered for this project figuring I could learn a bit and try something new. Not sure if I bit off more than I can chew now though.

Long story short the original page was designed literally back in the 90s so I wanted to see if I could do some aesthetic updates on top of some functional updates. I've managed to teach myself enough to understand the basics, but now that I"m trying to develop the functional updates I seem to be running into some troubles.

There is a tool that our department uses called "Associate Search" it's a company directory we use as part of our call center duties.  If we put a first or last name into the search field we get that associates photo, department, phone extension, etc.

The problem I'm running into is this - when clicking the link it opens into a new tab in IE and Chrome. But I want the link to open open in the same page - with the same side bar.

I've attached screenshots to show what I'm thinking. I apologize if this is a huge newb question - but i am a 100% newb at this lol so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is what the site currently looks like:[Current Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0qyY.jpg)

Here is a rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

[Wanted End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TseJy.jpg)

Current Code:

```
<!-- Nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://***.com/public/associatelookup.asp">Associate Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/cbdWNsf) < here is what the page currently looks like.

Comment: What does the markup of the link look like? From the sounds of things, you might have `target="_blank"` in the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

### Original

As Dryden mentioned, it sounds like you have a `target="_blank"` in your anchor tag.

`target="_self"` will open it up in the same page (this is default).

### Edit

With the new information here a somethings you could do, be aware this list is by far from exhaustive but are three simple solutions to achieve your desired result.

1. Use JQuery and show/hide the searchbar when the user clicks the link (JQuery will even do cool animations!).
2. Use plain JavaScript and do the same thing with show/hide when a link is clicked.
3. The simplest way would be to simply create another HTML file with the searchbar at the top and when a user clicks the link open that page in the browser window (duplicates code yes, but is simple).

Comment: I think you might have asked your question wrong, if what you have provided us is truly what is in the code then your new page should open in the same window. However it appears you want the search bar to ALWAYS be at the top of your webpage, is that correct?

Comment: yes that's what I'm looking to have done - but ONLY when the link has been clicked. does that make sense at all? I feel like I'm not describing what I'm looking for correctly still.

Comment: It makes sense, but I don't believe you explained that clearly in your question. If that's what you're after you have a number of options, you could use JQuery and show/hide the searchbar when the user clicks the link (JQuery will even do cool animations!), you can use plain JavaScript and do the samething with show/hide when a link is clicked, or the simplest way would be to simply create another HTML file with the searchbar at the top and when a user clicks the link open that page in the browser window (duplicates code yes, but is simple). There are other ways as well if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Usually pages open in a new tab when the link has the `target="_blank"` attribute set on them. Check in your code if there is such thing, remove it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Usually target="_blank" tag will be there which makes a click on the link open in new page.. remove that attribute in  a href tag(link).

```
<a href="www.abc.org" target="_blank">Visit abc</a>
```

Opens the link in new tab

```
<a href="www.abc.org" >Visit xyz!</a>
```

Opens the link in same tab

Comment: [Here is my code for the sidebar](http://imgur.com/Zs8XOaw). I have no idea how to add the code like you did in your comment so I hope this works.